# XMPP Delivery Receipts XEP-0184 with ASMACK

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I would like to send a receipt to each received message with Asmack but following code:

```
    DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(connection).setAutoReceiptsEnabled(true);
```

result in:

> 08-02 02:19:30.669: E/AndroidRuntime(32597): java.lang.**NullPointerException**
>   08-02 02:19:30.669: E/AndroidRuntime(32597):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.receipts.DeliveryReceiptManager.(DeliveryReceiptManager.java:62)
>   08-02 02:19:30.669: E/AndroidRuntime(32597):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.receipts.DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(DeliveryReceiptManager.java:81)

for sure connection object is not null.
I followed this pages to get to this point:
http://bamboo.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-TRUNK-59/commit

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android-Open-Source-App/Utility/yaxim/org/yaxim/androidclient/service/SmackableImp.java.htm

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? i am facing same problem. getting nullpointer exception

Comment: @AkhileshSk Look below, in comment I responded that I gave up and made my own "confirmation of receive", same did some other guy, so it seems still not solved.

Comment: Plz Can you tell me how you handled the confirmation of receipt?

Answer (score 1):

Do you call connect on the connection object before the above code?

Comment: Yes, I just gave up, and implemented id in my 'own way'. But if someone know solution maybe it would be helpful for somebody else out there.

Comment: I did it in my own way too. Much easier for fine grain control and I use it for other functions

Answer (score 1):

You can try before calling

```
<i>Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.ServiceDiscoveryManager");</i>
```